# If statement for vbnet

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I want to make an if statement with conditions that have 2 result

Example

```
if (id = "25" OR "36") then
print "The id is 25 or 36"
else
print "the id is not 25 or 36"
end if
```

My concern is in the if condition statement for "OR"

I try with "AND" but this only takes id = 25 as true whereas id = 36 as false

I try with "OR" "ORELSE" "XOR" this takes everything as true.

I try || sign but I got syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the comparision after the or:

`If (id = "25" Or id = "36") Then`

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the variable to check each time

`If id = "25" or id = "36" Then`

Alternatively, if this is likely to expand to include other numbers, you could use

`If {"25","36"}.Contains(id) Then`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use a Select Case statement:

```
Select Case id
     Case "25", "36"
          Print("The id is 25 or 36")
     Case Else
          Print("The id is not 25 or 36")
End Select
```

This works the same way as an if..else statement, but allows you to easily supply different test expressions.